# Issue with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, H2 db inetgration test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, junit, integration

I am trying to write an integration test using h2 db, I am getting an error as "error: cannot access BlockJUnit4ClassRunner" at the line @RunWith()

Can any one suggest something please? I have no clue, even If I comment out everything in the test it would not build and give the same error, so I don't think what's in the test that causing the issue

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-applicationContext.xml" })
public class WfsDBTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {}
```

Please help
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you use wrong version of JUnit.

Make sure that you use JUnit 4.x and there are no other versions of JUnit in your classpath. Try to use the latest version.

Comment: You are right there were two junit dependencies that were interfering. That solved the issue, Thank you very much!